# Best way to deal with calculating and formatting data in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a fairly simple requirement to render a table of start/end-dates in my Javascript application:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Number of weeks</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2 Jan 2017</td>
      <td>9 Jan 2017</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- etc -->
 </table>
```

My raw data looks like this:

```
[
    {
       Id: 8672,
       StartDate: "2017-01-02",
       Weeks: 1
    }
    // More rows
]
```

My question is what is the best way to perform the calculation and formatting of these fields so as to maintain separation of concerns without adversely effecting performance? I've considered a number of approaches:

**Transforming the data before it is stored in the data store**

I could use the reducer function, or the piece of code that raises the "data loaded" action to map the original data into something that more closely resembles the format and fields required by the UI Component. This has the advantage of making the UI component simple but it does tie the data and reducer quite closely to the user interface control.

**Performing the calculation & formatting in the UI Component**

I could just format and parse the data in the user UI Component. This seems like a bad idea because it ties the UI component closely to the format of the data.

**Performing the transformations in mapStateToProps of the table UI**

This seems like a good approach, but it would force the react-redux bindings to re-render the entire table every time the state changes because each render will result in the `dates` prop having a different identity

```
const datesRow = (date) => (
    <tr>
       <td>{date.StartDate}</td>
       <td>{date.EndDate}</td>
       <td>{date.NumberOfWeeks}</td>
    </tr>
)

const datesTable = ({dates}) => (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Number of weeks</th>
      </tr>
      { dates.map(datesRow) }
    </table>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  dates: state.dates.map(x => transformDates(x))
});

const DatesTableContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(datesTable);
```

**Making the row UI component and doing the mapping there**

This seems to maintain the loose coupling between UI and state offered by the previous option, but also allows incremental updates of the UI. It just seems quite heavy on containers. Is this a good idea?

```
const datesRow = (date) => (
    <tr>
       <td>{date.StartDate}</td>
       <td>{date.EndDate}</td>
       <td>{date.NumberOfWeeks}</td>
    </tr>
)

const mapStateToPropsForRow = (state, ownProps) => {
  const dateItem = lookupDateById(ownProps.dateId);
  return {
      StartDate: formatDate(dateItem.StartDate),
      EndDate: calculateAndFormatEndDate(dateItem.EndDate),
      NumberOfWeeks: dateItem.NumberOfWeeks
  }
};

const DatesRowContainer = connect(mapStateToPropsForRow)(datesRow);

const mapStateToPropsForRow = (state, ownProps) => {
  const dateItem = lookupDateById(ownProps.dateId);
  return {
      StartDate: formatDate(dateItem.StartDate),
      EndDate: calculateAndFormatEndDate(dateItem.EndDate),
      NumberOfWeeks: dateItem.NumberOfWeeks
  }
};

const datesTable = ({id}) => (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Number of weeks</th>
      </tr>
      <DatesRowContainer dateId={id} />
    </table>
);

const mapStateToPropsForTable = (state) => ({
  dates: state.dates.map(x => {id: x.id})
});

const DatesTableContainer = connect(mapStateToPropsForTable)(datesTable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be to remap it in your reducer. There, it will only have to be done once, as opposed to doing it **on each render** if you were to remap it in your `mapStateToProps`- or `render`-functions. Your data-fetch (or loading in your data from whatever source) is already a "*slow action*" anyway, so if adding the remapping there, won't bother the user.

In either of those last two, you could potentially make your app stutter quite a bit, especially if your dataset is large or your remap expensive.
Having a stutter every rerender, however, isn't ideal.

Alternatively you could probably use the [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library, but I haven't used this myself yet, so I cannot really give any comments on that.

Comment: Good option in my opinion. Just keep in mind that reducers must be pure and action creators don't need to be pure. So I'd put that logic inside the action creator and dispatch updated data.

Comment: Maybe, but usually you have that data in your action, which is a parameter of your reducer. As long as your data is immutable and/or you do it correctly, your reducer will remain pure.